# Laravel - Controller not getting the request from form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have this form:

```
<form action="{{route('login')}}" id="loginForm" method="POST">
           <div class="text-center" style="font-size: 30px; font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;">Login</div><br />
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-label"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
            <input class="input-group-field" id="lemail" name="lemail" placeholder="Insert your email" type="email" required>
        </div>
        <p class="help-text" id="email">Type in your email and password to log in.</p>

        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-label"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
            <input class="input-group-field" id="lpassword" name="lpassword" placeholder="Type in your password" type="password" required>
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <br />
        <div class="align-center">
        <button type="submit" class="button secondary align-center" href="#">Login</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

As you see, I have `action="{{route('login')}}"` as I want to use that route:

```
Route::post('/', [
   'as' => 'login',
   'uses' => 'LoginUser@login'
]);
```

And this is the function:

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'lemail' => 'required|string|email|max:255',
            'lpassword' => 'required|string|min:6|max:128',
        ]);

        $email = $request->input('lemail');
        $password = $request->input('lpassword');

        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {

            // Authentication passed...
            return redirect()->intended('/home')
                ->with('flash_notice', 'You are successfully logged in.');
        }

        return redirect()->intended('/')
            ->with('flash_error', 'Your username/password combination was incorrect.');
    }
```

The problem is that after I fill the fields and send the form, it tells me that the email and password fields are empty, but they are not.

#### This only happens if I set the "action" and do the route like that, otherwise it works fine.

I did this because I have it in the footer and I want it to work on all pages, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: what is the post url in the form ? after rendered ?

Comment: @Coco Have you checked the generated route after `{{ route('login') }}`? Have you checked the list of your routes? `php artisan route:list`.

Comment: I did `{{ action('LoginUser@login') }}` and it works, is it good?

Comment: Which laravel version are you using?

Comment: Are you using built in Laravel login/auth stuff?  Do you have `Route::auth();` in your routes file?  Maybe they are conflicting?

Comment: Did you try removing the href from your submit button?

Answer (score 0):

Use your route as:

```
Route::post('/', 'LoginUser@login')->name('login');
```

Comment: It still tells me that the fields are empty

Answer (score 0):

Give name in your route

```
Route::post('/', [
   'as' => 'login',
   'uses' => 'LoginUser@login'
])->name('login');
```

And also i think you forgot your **{{ csrf_field() }}** inside your form or token :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a name attribute in your input tag.
2. In your login function add dd($request).  You have to delete them later.
3. In the dd output on the "request" array you will see the values of the parameters you forwarded from the blade.